# sorting NSArray of NSDictionaries using NSSortDescriptor not working

Tags: objective-c, sorting

I have an array `unsortedPosts` full of dictionaries, which look like this if I print out the contents in the terminal:

```
{
    "created_at" = 1332584959;
    id = "61926802418418";
    network = "net1";
    text = "text1";
    url = "https://www.google.com";
},
{
    "created_at" = 1332581096;
    id = "6192689218418";
    network = "net1";
    text = "text1";
    url = "https://www.yahoo.com";
},
{
    "created_at" = 1332581074;
    id = "6192688628418";
    network = "net1";
    text = "text1";
    url = "https://www.aol.com";
}
```

I want to sort them by the `created_at` field (unix time stamps). I'm using NSSortDescriptor like so:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"\"created_at\"" ascending:TRUE];
NSMutableArray *sortDescriptors = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
NSArray *sortedSocialPosts;
sortedSocialPosts = [unsortedSocialPosts sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

But the output isn't sorted.

**Edit**

I tried running it without using the escaped quotes around `created_at` (per @Eimantas answer):

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"created_at" ascending:TRUE];
NSMutableArray *sortDescriptors = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
NSArray *sortedSocialPosts;
sortedSocialPosts = [unsortedSocialPosts sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

But I get this error:

```
-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a2a3c0
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a2a3c0'
```

Comment: If the array was printed with `NSLog()` the quotes around `created_at` are just an artifact of the way it prints stuff - most likely because of the underscore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the escaped quotes, just pass in `@"created_at"` and you will be good. The quotes are sometimes printed when doing `NSLog()` calls. I'm pretty sure that you can actually access the creation timestamp just by accessing `@"created_at"` key with `valueForKey:` method.

**update**

This may mean that some of the `created_at` values may be `NSString` instances and some - `NSNumber` instances. Can you confirm that all of the created_at values are of the  same type? (Use `NSLog(@"%@", [[unsortedSocialPosts valueForKey:@"created_at"] valueForKey:@"class"]);`.